# Detect new nested fields after resource.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested association `company has_many :employees`

I have a form with cocoon where I can add new nested_fields.

In my controller, I first try to save the resource and the nested fields (to eventually trigger validation errors), but then if the validation passes and the resource along with the nested fields are saved, I need to perform a custom action only on the new nested fields (new records that didn't exist before).

How can I select only the new fields ? (Note that this happens after a `@resource.save`)

```
...
if @company.save
  custom_action(@company.employees.select do |employee|
    # Select only newly created employees
  end)
end
```

I don't think it's relevant here, but I am using Mongoid.

Comment: Can you not just use an after_create model callback?

Comment: @hypern I could, but this is really something that should be done (from a logic point of view) in the controller. Later I am actually planning to also have different controllers that do not send emails after adding similar `nested_associations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting these newely created employees in array **before saving** them like this:

```
new_employess = @company.employess.select {|e| e.new_record? }
```

And then you would be able to do whatever you want after **@company.save**

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using the default updated_at and created_at stamps that rails employs (or anything similar), you could simply get the time immediately before you call your batch save, and then grab all of the elements belonging to the parent that were created after that point. For example:

```
# Gets the current time
time = Time.now

if @company.save
    custom_action(@company.nested_items.where("created_at >= ?", time) do
        # Processing only newly created employees
    end)
end
```

Comment: You should not rely on timestamps in a such short window. If 2 users updates the record at the same time, the objects would be used twice in the `custom_action` block